# SSH on cygwin works but not on my linux box

Tags: ssh, openssh

They have exactly the same .ssh files and permissions and they are 'ssh'ing to the same locale (git fetch, actually)

Here is Linux box:OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

```
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA         2a:7d:aa:b0:bd:c7:7e:98:6c:71:1b:cf:7b:27:e4:c8:28:2d:7c:1c
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 656 bytes for a total of 1965
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,publickey
```

..

here is Cygwin: OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

```
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA MD5:b4:22:b7:ca:60:69:dc:f0:d8:42:18:ed:61:6c:08:70
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have CentOS/RHEL machine (according to the OpenSSH version) and you have wrong SELinux labels somewhere on the way to these files. `restorecon -FR ~/.ssh` from the users shell should fix them. If not, please provide the listing of  `ls -lZd ~ ~./.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys_file`.

Note that some error should be visible in the server log (`/var/log/secure`) when you bump log level.